# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n+2)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem is to find sum

$$\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{4}{4!}+\frac{9}{5!}\cdots$$

What I knew doesn't apply on this problem

Some series are telescoping, some types are solvable using binomial , both look useless here
Binomial gives

$$n (n-1) (n-2)x^3=1$$
 $$n (n-1)( n-2)(n-3)x^4=4$$

What approach to use here?

Comment: I assume you mean $3!, 4!,\dots$. Or does $!n$ mean something else?

Comment: No nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the range so that it starts at $n = 0$ and substitute $n^2 = (n+2)(n+1) - 3(n+2) + 4$ to obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n+2)!} &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{(n+2)!} -
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3(n+2)}{(n+2)!} +
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4}{(n+2)!} \\ &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} -
3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!} +
4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+2)!} \\ &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} -
3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} +
4\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \\ &=
(1-3+4) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} -3\left(-\frac{1}{0!}\right) +4\left(-\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}\right) \\ &=
2e+3-8 \\ &= 2e-5.
\end{align*}
$$
More generally, this shows that for every polynomial $P(n)$ over the rationals and $k \geq 0$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{P(n)}{(n+k)!} = \alpha e + \beta
$$
for some rationals $\alpha,\beta$, and these can be calculated by presenting $P(n)$ as a linear combination of the polynomials
$$ 1, n+k, (n+k)(n+k-1), (n+k)(n+k-1)(n+k-2), \ldots. $$
In your case, we needed to represent $n^2$ as a linear combination of $1,n+2,(n+2)(n+1)$. The general form of such a combination is
$$ n^2 = A+B(n+2)+C(n+2)(n+1) = Cn^2 + (3C+B)n + (2C+2B+A). $$
Equating coefficients, we get the linear system $C = 1$, $3C+B = 0$, $2C+2B+A = 0$, which we can solve by back-substitution to obtain $C=1$, $B=-3$, $A=4$. Back-substitution works in general, and we obtain a simple and efficient algorithm for evaluating the general form of this series.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n^2}{(n+2)!}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{((n+2)-2)^2}{(n+2)!}$

Comment: This is actually not the correct identity. The identity you really want to use is $n^2 = (n+2)(n+1) - 3(n+2) + 4$.

Comment: Answer came out to be correct using this way too

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n^2 }}{{\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n^2 }}{{\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}}  =  - 5 + 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( {n - 1} \right)^2 }}{{n!}}}  =  - 5 + 2e
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 s = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n^2 }}{{\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( {n - 2} \right)^2 }}{{n!}}}  =  - \frac{{\left( {0 - 2} \right)^2 }}{{0!}} - \frac{{\left( {1 - 2} \right)^2 }}{{1!}} + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( {n - 2} \right)^2 }}{{n!}}}  \\ 
 s =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( {n - 2} \right)^2 }}{{n!}}}  =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( {n - 2} \right)^2 }}{{n!}}}  \\ 
 s =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n^2  - 4n + 4}}{{n!}}}  =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n^2 }}{{n!}}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{4n}}{{n!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{4}{{n!}}}  \\ 
 s =  - 5 + \frac{{0^2 }}{{0!}} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n^2 }}{{n!}}}  - \frac{{4\left( 0 \right)}}{{0!}} - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{4n}}{{n!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{4}{{n!}}}  \\ 
 s =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{n}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{4}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{4}{{n!}}} \quad ;\quad \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{4}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{4}{{n!}}} } \right) \\ 
 s =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{n}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n - 1 + 1}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  =  - 5 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{n - 1}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  \\ 
 s =  - 5 + 2e \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look at the series expansion of $e^x$. Specifically, consider something like $e^n$, and try to manipulate your series, so that it looks "close" to this series.